# How can i change the color in the panel when a program needs attention?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, colors, gui

I'm running Linux Mint 14. I want to change the color in the panel when a program requires your attention (like when you receive a chat message).

Not the color of the entire panel, but only the box with the program name and icon.

Is this possible?

Comment: Linux Mint is available with different Desktop Engines (MATE, Cinnamon, KDE etc.), so you should find out/tell us which one you are running first of all, I believe?

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this you have to edit the CSS related to your theme. If you're using the default Linux Mint theme:

1. Go to /usr/share/cinnamon/theme
2. Open cinnamon.css in your favorite text editor. You may require root access.
3. Look for `.window-list-item-demands-attention`
4. edit these values to whatever you want, either a new color gradient or a solid color.

Unfortunately, there is no way to give each program its own color using this method, as far as I'm aware.